# How can my Flutter content resize when the mobile keyboard is shown?

Tags: android, flutter

I have been trying to make a `BottomAppBar` containing a `TextField` push itself and the `Scaffold` body above the soft keyboard when it is opened on a mobile device. The content of the screen is a `ListView`. When a user taps the `TextField`, it should resize the `Scaffold` and its content to accommodate the keyboard, but it does not. I am at quite a loss for this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(
      items: List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => 'Item $i'),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items;

  const MyApp({super.key, required this.items});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Long List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: const BottomAppBar(child: TextField()),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          prototypeItem: ListTile(
            title: Text(items.first),
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(items[index]),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Above is a simple recreation of the issue (as far as I understand). `List.generate` creates items for a `ListView`, and the `BottomAppBar` is parenting the TextField.

Below is my actual code I have for this project, in case my interpretation of the issue is wrong.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

import 'variables.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: TextField(
            onSubmitted: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) return;
              final message = <String, dynamic>{
                "message": value,
                "user": "Anonymous",
                "timestamp": DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
              };

              db.collection("messages").add(message);
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: ChatMessageStream(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChatMessageStream extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatMessageStream({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChatMessageStream> createState() => _ChatMessageStreamState();
}

class _ChatMessageStreamState extends State<ChatMessageStream> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _messagesStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('messages')
      .orderBy('timestamp')
      .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _messagesStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong :(');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(data['message']),
                );
              })
              .toList()
              .cast(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My assumption is that because the `ListView` is a scrollable element, the built-in resizing of the scaffold body gets ignored (`resizeToAvoidBottomInset` defaults to true). What can I do to fix this issue? I do want to note that keeping the `TextField` in the `BottomAppBar` isn't a strict necessity, but it is nice.

Comment: I don't think that is possible right now. But you can wrap you listview in flexible and make flexible and textfield as children of column to achieve your desired result.

Comment: @Rahul That works!... mostly. The `TextField` will leave the bottom of the screen if `ListView` widget is empty, or there is not enough content to fill the viewport. Also somewhat related, the `ListView` does not scroll when it gets resized, so the keyboard obstructs the view until a user scrolls manually again.

Comment: `Expanded` on my `ListView` and `Flexible` on my `TextField` seems to counteract this issue. Will post an answer once I figure out the scrolling thing.